# PySimpleGUI file browser specific file type

Tags: python, pandas, file, browser, pysimplegui

i am trying to browse a only excel files but How to restrict the file type in PySimpleGUI browse button .

Answer (score 16):

```
layout =  [[sg.In() ,sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),))]]
```

Comment: Glad you found it. The documentation is located at http://www.PySimpleGUI.org and discusses this `file_types` parameter as well as WARNING that this parameter will not work on the Mac platform (for the tkinter version of PySimpleGUI).

Comment: Saving you a click with a direct link to their documentation: https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/